# TableView crash when adding new item when reach the last element of the tableview Swift 4

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

I have a `tableView` which will display 20 item when the app start,then when scroll to the bottom,will pull another 20 item from server and display to `TableView` as well

At first I call this to get the 1st 20 item to display in my `tableview`,and this is working fine

```
   var posts = [Item]() 

//here is the latest 20 posts
    func fetchPost(itemId : Int){
        Alamofire.request(MY_URL!, method: .get).responseJSON{
            response in
            switch response.result{
            case .success(let result):
                //here parse the JSON.
                let json = JSON(result)
                guard let feedArr = json["item"].array else{
                    return
                }

                for item in feedArr {
                    if let item = item.dictionary,let feed = Item.init(dict: item){
                        self.posts.append(feed)
                    }
                }

                self.myTableView.reloadData()

                break
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the TableView function,which is standard

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableCellClass
    cell.posts = self.posts[indexPath.row]
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

Here I get `Id` for the last item in `TableView` and fetch the next 20 item by using `fetchPost()` method at the top

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row + 1 == posts.count {
            //here is the last item of the feed
            let lastPostId = self.posts[indexPath.row].postId
            self.fetchPost(postId: lastPostId)
        }
    }
```

But now when I reach the bottom of the TableView,let `lastPostId` is valid,and get the response from server,but the app crashed and keep giving this error :

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT  <--this one in AppDelagate class
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException (lldb) <<-- in console

Besides that,when I keep scrolling down,then I scrolling up again,the same error also appear,and all the element inside the TableViewCell all move disorganized(means that not same with what I organized in storyboard)

**What I done so far**

Check the connection of `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` is connected with `MyTableCell` class .. This is checked,all connected

**So my question is**

1) What cause this error in TableView,I know this is a very general error,but how can I solved this with this little information from xcode? I dont know which line of code is causing the problem.

2) What is the correct way to display the next 20 item with same structure like the previous in a same `TableView`?

Please help.Thank you

Comment: This error means that you've improperly unwrapped a `nil` somewhere. If for the life of you you can't find it, one by one remove every property (most likely just in that swift file) that can be nil (or temporarily replace it with something that you know cannot be nil) and run the app and you should find the culprit.

Comment: Comment this line and try to run. "cell.posts = self.posts[indexPath.row]" . U can check, ur logic is working or not.